# after eas build command i have this error

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, npx, eas

[expo logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COTkk.png)

i want to publish my app but after command eas build i have this problems.

Prebuild

```
  Android package Learn more: https://expo.fyi/android-package
```

2[stderr] CommandError: Input is required, but 'npx expo' is in non-interactive mode.
3[stderr] Project must have a `android.package` set in the Expo config (app.json or app.config.js).

i want to publish my app but after command eas build i have this problems.

Prebuild

```
  Android package Learn more: https://expo.fyi/android-package
```

2[stderr] CommandError: Input is required, but 'npx expo' is in non-interactive mode.
3[stderr] Project must have a `android.package` set in the Expo config (app.json or app.config.js).